# Jquery Highlight function not working

Tags: jquery

I am trying to find all the numeric values in a textbox text and highlight them but nothing is happening. The code is below. Can you please help identify what is that I am doing wrong?

```
 model Notes.Models.NotesModel
 <html>
   <head>
      <title>Notes</title>
       <style>
            .highlight {background-color :yellow;}
       </style>
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

          function PIIHighlight() {
                                 var regex = new RegExp("\D+", "gi");
                                 alert(document.getElementById("Notes").value.toString());
                                 return $("Notes").each(function ()    {  document.getElementById("Notes").value.replace(regex,function (matched) { return "<span class=\"" + highlight + "\">" + matched + "</span>"; });
                                   });
                               };
       </script>
    </head>

    <body>
       <p> <input id="Notes" name="notes" type="text" spellcheck="true" class="txtbox" style="font-size:12pt;height:220px;width:600px;" /></p>
       <p> <button onclick="PIIHighlight();">Check</button></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thank you!

Comment: What errors do you get? Also, `$("Notes").each` makes no sense as IDs must be unique, so you're iterating over one item. And if you're using jQuery, then *use* jQuery and don't do `document.getElementById("Notes").value.toString()`. Do `$('$Notes').val()`.

Comment: Maybe tell us what you are trying to achieve because the code's quite the mess. Mixed JavaScript and jQuery, each on an ID, returning HTML inside an input? And so on. Tell us what you are trying to do.

Comment: And you can't put spans around the text in an input and expect them to render as HTML. Also, `$("Notes")` should be `$("#Notes")`

Comment: Am getting no error. I was doing "this.each" earlier and the error was  '0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'each''.Even if I try $("$Notes").val().replace(regex, function (matched) { return "<span class=\"" + highlight + "\">" + matched + "</span>"; }); no change, the number is not being highlighted.

Comment: The requirement is to identify all the numeric values in a textbox text and highlight them. I thought of using regex to identify all the numbers and highlight them using the jquery function.

Comment: `$("$Notes")` isn't what you want either. `$("#Notes")`. But again, you can't have HTML like spans in a text box

Comment: You *could* use a contenteditable div. But still, you don't need each on an ID selector...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This makes it looks more appealing to what you need I guess, but relies on the contenteditable property...

```
model Notes.Models.NotesModel 
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Notes</title>
   <style>
        .highlight {background-color :yellow;}
   </style>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

       $(document).ready(function(){document.getElementById("Notes").focus();});
      function PIIHighlight() {
                             var values = document.getElementById("Notes").innerHTML.split(" ");
                             values.forEach(function(elem, idx){
          //$("values").each(function(){ 
                                 if(!isNaN(elem))
                                     {
                                         values[idx] = "<span class='highlight'>" + elem + "</span>";
                                     }
                               });
                             values = values.join(" ");
                             document.getElementById("Notes").innerHTML = values;
                           }
   </script>
 </head>

 <body>
    <p> <div id="Notes" contenteditable="true" name="notes" type="text" spellcheck="true" class="txtbox" style="font-size:12pt;height:220px;width:600px;padding:5px; border:1px solid blue;"></div></p>
   <p> <button onclick="PIIHighlight();">Check</button></p>
 </body>
</html>
```

Hope it helps.